# ¿Por qué no funciona mi @ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un proyecto en MVC 5 donde el usuario debe iniciar sesión, y con el uso de una variable "Session" se toma su nombre para mostrarlo en el header de _Layout.cshtml, esto mediante un `@Viewbag.session`, pero por alguna razón no esta funcionando. Este es el código:

En el modelo:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClsLogin
{
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Contrasena { get; set; }

    public string SessionValue {get; set; }
}
```

En el controlador:

```html
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Login(ClsLogin User)
 {
   string message = "";
        
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      message = "Success";
                
      Session["SessionUser"] = User.NombreUsuario;
      var sessionuser = new ClsLogin();

      if (Session["SessionUser"] != null)
      {
       sessionuser.SessionValue =       Session["SessionUser"].ToString();
      }
  
      else
      {
       sessionuser.SessionValue = "La sesión ha expirado";
      }

      ViewBag.session = sessionuser;          
   }           

    else
    {
      message = "Uno de los campos es incorrecto";
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
     return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
       
    else
    {
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Y finalmente la vista principal _Layout que es donde el Viewbag no funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>ASP.NET Proyect</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/css/_Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<!--Encabezado-->
<header>
    <h2 class="padding">Bienvenido</h2>
    @ViewBag.session
</header>

<!--Menu-->
<div class="menu-content">
    @Html.Partial("_Menu")
</div>

<!--Contenido-->
<div class="body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Intente también así `@Html.TextBox("mensaje", (string)ViewBag.session)` y no dio resultado ¿Alguna idea de en qué me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Cuando dices "no está funcionando" ¿te refieres a que el `ViewBag.session` está vacío?

Comment: use un breakpoint para ver si tomaba el nombre del usuario, y sí lo hace, pero al momento de pasarlo a la vista esta vacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que los datos de `ViewBag` solo están disponibles durante un mismo request.  Lo que veo que ocurre es que llenas el valor en el action `Login` y luego rediriges hacia el action `Index`, es en este segundo request que los datos ya no están disponibles.

Lo que puedes hacer es seguir usando `Session` en tu vista que si es una clase que guarda los datos entre diferentes llamadas

```
<header>
    <h2 class="padding">Bienvenido</h2>
    @Session["..."]
</header>
```

o inclusive usar las propiedades del objeto `User` si es que solo necesitas el nombre

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias :3